# Display dynamic column name using angularjs for html table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I just prepared a data and want to display in html table but the problem is that every time I call the $http service it returns n number of columns. So basically what I want to display is that first row of the data should be used for column names and rest are rows. Sure the column names are not fixed there could be n number of columns. Below is the sample data:

```html
[["Product",2016,2017],["A",50.92,550],["B",10,0],["C",20,0]]

or 

[["Product",2015, 2016,2017],["A",80, 50.92,550],["B",20, 10,0],["C",75,20,0]]
```

I tried this but not getting how to print the first row as column and display remaining rows beneath.

```html
<table style="width:100%; font-size:11px; " ng-repeat="(key, value) in NewTable">

  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#00372B; height: 50px; ">
      <th style="padding:1%; color:white;" colspan="3">{{ key }}:{{value}}</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
</table>
```

Request someone to provide the solution with angular-filter as well so I can add some calculated columns on the table as well.
Thanks.

Comment: **Mathias W**, see my updated question.

Comment: Also post your angular code where you are constructing the data.

Comment: **Ali Baig**, actually my angular code is very complex that's why I planned not to post all the stuff which can simply confuse others to understand or possible will take bit longer to resolve the issue.

Comment: OK I have added my answer below on my understanding based on the given data. Please post you feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK based on the data provided, give it a try

```
<table>
  <thead ng-repeat="columns in NewTable | limitTo:1">
    <tr ng-repeat="column in columns">
      <th>{{ column }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in NewTable.slice(1,NewTable.length)">
      <td ng-repeat="row in rows">{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Where NewTable is the array of data in your angular controller/component.

Comment: It does make the first row separate from other rows, but how I can fetch the values of each object. I mean it displays data in this form: ["Product",2016,2017] ["A",50.92,550] ["B",10,0] ["C",20,0] and moreover after this I want to use some of the angular-filter for the calculated fields like sum, avg ...etc.

Comment: Yes I did something : <tr ng-repeat="entry in NewTable.slice(1,NewTable.length)">
                        
                        <td ng-repeat="ent in entry">{{ ent }}</td>
                    </tr> and it works like a charm, but again can I use the angular-filter with these.

Comment: @Saleem I have updated my answer based on your first comment, try to see if it works now.

Comment: Yes you can create a custom filter for that and use it after the ng-repeat block ends. It will be a piece of cake ;)

Comment: **Ali Baig**, Can I append a calculated column at the end of each row using angular-fitler?

Comment: Why would you need the calculated column after each row? You can use angular filter anywhere in your code but calculations after each row doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133682/discussion-between-saleem-and-ali-baig).

Comment: Can we chat in room?

Comment: **Ali Baig**, did you get the solution for calculated columns.